# How to use a pointer to swap arrays

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers

My task is to create a square matrix and this square matrix needs to be multiplied to the power n and m represents the size of the square matrix.

The users input will be saved into the original array and the temporary array at first. Once the sum is calculated it will be saved into results and then I am supposed to swap the result array with the temporary array.

```
int main()
{
    // define variables
    int m, n;
    int matrix_1;
    int original[5][5];
    int result[5][5];
    int temporary[5][5];
    int *ptrResult = &result[0][0];
    int *ptrTemp = &temporary[0][0];
    int *hold = &result[0][0];

    // input from user with validations
    do
    {
        printf("Please input an array size in between 1 to 5: ");
        scanf("%d", &m);
    } while (m < 1 || m > 5);

    do
    {
        printf("Please input an integer as the multiplication power: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n <= 0);

    // input for elements in array
    if (m == 1)
    {
        printf("Value of element in matrix R with size M: ");
        scanf("%d", &original[0][0]);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                printf("[%d][%d] = ", i, k);
                scanf("%d", &original[i][k]);
                temporary[i][k] = original[i][k];
            }
        }
    }

    int sum = 0;
    int a;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) // Power nth
    {   
        for (int c = 0; c < m; c++) // Row
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < m; d++) // Column
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
                {

                    sum += temporary[c][k] * original[k][d];
                }
                result[c][d] = sum;
                sum = 0;                    
            }
            *hold = *(ptrResult + d);
            *(ptrResult + d) = *(ptrTemp + d);
            *(ptrTemp +d) = *hold;
        }    
    }
```

My basic knowledge on pointers is very bad as it is a very new concept to me.

What i want to do is everytime my loop calculates one of the sum I want to replace it from the result array into the temporary array. Forgot to mention that this original matrix is actually a 5x5 matrix but lets say the users wants m =3 which only fills a 3x3 matrix inside the 5x5 matrix.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "use a pointer to swap arrays". Please describe the expected behaviour in terms of the variables in your code. Which pointers exactly are you referring to and what do you want each of those to point to at the end of your program? And your code is incomplete which adds to the difficulty in understanding your question. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You (still) don't show many variable declarations except the loop controls.  In particular, you don't show `hold`, `ptrResult`, or `ptrTemp`.  The `d` in `*(ptrResult + d)` is not the `d` in the loop above, which is confusing.  You keep on swapping the same values because the outer `d` and the three pointers don't change in the code.  Please provide the MCVE ([MCVE]) previously mentioned.

Comment: the d is meant to be the d from the loop. im sorry im very noob at this.

Comment: @Jeevan - why do you want to use pointers instead of the simple `array[x][y]` form?

Answer (score 1):

It is not fully clear to me what it is you want to do. But there is a few things that is/seems wrong with your code.

The code can't compile because the variable `d` is used out of scope.

```
        for (int d = 0; d < m; d++) // Here d is defined, i.e. in scope
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
            {

                sum += temporary[c][k] * original[k][d];
            }
            result[c][d] = sum;
            sum = 0;                    
        }   // Here d gets out of scope


        *hold = *(ptrResult + d);  // So d can't be used here and
                                   // you'll get a compile error
```

In principle your swap code is ok in the sense that it does swap two values.

```
        *hold = *(ptrResult + d);          // Put X into temp
        *(ptrResult + d) = *(ptrTemp + d); // Overwrite X with Y
        *(ptrTemp +d) = *hold;             // Overwrite Y with X
                                           // So X and Y has been swapped
```

But take a look at your `hold` pointer. What is it pointing to?

```
int *hold = &result[0][0];
```

It points to the first element in `result`. So whenever you swap, you destroy the first element of `result`. That is probably not what you want. Instead make another variable for swapping. Like:

```
int temp;
int* hold = & temp;
```

However, in general I don't understand why you want to do it with pointers. Why not use the simple `array[x][y]` form.

Comment: The task given to use is supposed to enhance our knowledge on pointers which is why I want to use pointers instead of a standard loop for swapping.  How do I ensure that my ptrResult replaces ptrTemp for each of the elements in the array while also taking into account the fact that is a 5x5 matrix even though the user only wants a 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

`int *ptrResult=&result[0][0];` and `int *hold=&result[0][0];`both  are pointing to first element of the array.

```
*hold = *(ptrResult + d);          
*(ptrResult + d) = *(ptrTemp + d); 
 *(ptrTemp +d) = *hold;
```

to avoid declare hold as `int.

```
int hold;
```